# Remove or hide menu from the jQuery iframe modal dialog load from url

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I remove/hide menu header from the popup modal dialog from url?

```
var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen id="frameIdcustomer"></iframe>');
        var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: "auto",
            height: "auto",               
            close: function () {
                iframe.attr("src", "");
            }
        });
        $("#btn_newCustomer").on("click", function AddCust(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var src = "../MasterPages/CustomerMaster.aspx";
            var title = "Customer Master";
            var width = "980";
            var height = "530";
            iframe.attr({
                width: +width,
                height: +height,
                src: src
            });                
            dialog.dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
            $("#frameIdcustomer").contents().find("#menuheaderr").hide();
        });
```

I tried `$("menuheader").hide()` but it's not working.

`$("#frameIdcustomer").contents().find("#menuheaderr").hide();` is also not working.

Comment: If you type _$("#frameIdcustomer").contents().find("#menuheaderr").hide();_ in your developer console after it's opened does it work?

Comment: yes it s working after it's opened i debug and if i write  the same code so how can i do befre showing the window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframe = $('<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" allowfullscreen id="frameIdcustomer" onload="hideMenu()"></iframe>');

    function hideMenu(){
    $("#frameIdcustomer").contents().find("#menuheaderr").hide();
    }
```

To find element you need to wait until iframe contents is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame might still be loading when you call the line to hide the header. Try placing that line in a callback function instead.

```
var dialog = $("<div></div>").append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    ...
    complete: function() { $("#frameIdcustomer").contents().find("#menuheaderr").hide(); }
});
```

Comment: i tried  complete: function() { alert(hi"); } not working ? i am using update panel in my aspx page